# Exceções customizadas em JAX-RPC

Tags: java, web-service, exceção

Estou realizando algumas melhorias em alguns Web Services JAX-RPC aqui na empresa.
Gostaria de saber se é possível trabalhar com exceções customizadas neste caso e, se possível, se alguém pode exemplificar uma implementação.

Já fiz algumas tentativas com base em alguns tópicos (assim que encontrá-los novamente posto aqui), mas até agora sem sucesso.

Comment: *Já fiz algumas tentativas*: poderia informar quais foram, para não ser preciso refazê-las? Pretende retornar as excecões como *SOAP *falts* ou seus contratos especificam de alguma forma específica? Informe mais detalhes do seu cenário, fica difícil ajudar sem informação

Comment: Existe esse artigo que trata como funciona as excessões RPC e como utilizar Checked Exceptions para mapear o tipo de erro e tratar conforme você definir. Veja se isso pode te ajudar: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tip-jaxrpc/